# Updating UI without needing reload/refresh when deleting/adding new rows to DataTables?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

[image]

I have a table that is rendered using DataTables in a cshtml file. I am adding and removing users. I add users using select2 tag and remove a user from the table.

The table body has a row with a onclick function that deletes that specific row. And select two uses a button to add a new row.

All is working fine, one issue left is that atm I have to reload the page to render the changes.

Is there a simple way to add and delete a row and render it without refreshing the page? Will I need AJAX for this?

```
[Authorize(Policy = CMPConstants.AdminUsersOnly)]
    public IActionResult GroupDetails(string groupName)
    { //return data model to render in cshtml,
        var trustMarqueAdmin = SetWrapperModel(groupName);
        return this.View(trustMarqueAdmin);
    }

     // model rendered in cshtml.
<table id="admin-users-table" class="table">
    @{
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.DisplayName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.GivenName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.Surname)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.CompanyName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.AccessLevel)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.AccessScope)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.PrismUser)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Remove
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-body-admin-users">
            @foreach (var member in Model.CurrentGroupMembers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.DisplayName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.GivenName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.Surname)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.CompanyName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.AccessLevel)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.AccessScope)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.PrismUser)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary delete-user-icon" onclick="RemoveFromGroup('@member.Id','@Model.TMGroup.Id','@member.GivenName','@member.Surname', '@Model.GroupName')">remove</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    }
</table>


 // on clicking add + plus button add members,
function AddToGroup(groupId, groupName) {
  $("#confirm-add-group").modal('show');

  $.post('/Home/AddToGroup', 
       { 
        userIdList: userIds, 
        groupId: groupId, 
        groupName:groupName 
    });
 }

// on clicking a delete button a row is deleted. 
function RemoveFromGroup(userId, groupId, fName, lName, groupName) {
  $(".confirm-delete").click(function () {
   $.post('/Home/RemoveFromGroup', { userId: userId, groupId: groupId });
  });
}


 // running data table here:
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#admin-users-table').DataTable({
     allowClear: true,
   });
 });


    [Authorize(Policy = CMPConstants.AdminUsersOnly)]
    public async Task RemoveFromGroup(string? userId, string? groupId)
    {
        await this.b2cRepository.DeleteUserFromGroup(userId, groupId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }


    [Authorize(Policy = CMPConstants.AdminUsersOnly)]
    public async Task AddToGroup(string groupId, string?[] userIdList, string groupName)
    {
        await this.b2cRepository.AddUserToGroup(groupId, userIdList, groupName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: You will need to load the DataTables data using AJAX and then refresh the table after adding a new row. Take a look [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax) to see how to setup ajax data sources and use `$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();` to reload the data.

Comment: Thank for the reply, but how can I keep the onlick attribute in the table rows so I can also delete a row? I get that I need to retrieve the data using Ajax and then populate it by appending the data to a table id.

Comment: You will need to attach the event on the button that you render the column. [This](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html) should help get you started.

Comment: You can use `$('#admin-users-table').DataTable().rows.add()` and `$('#admin-users-table').DataTable().rows.remove()`

Comment: How would I pass in the id of the row I wanted to remove using:('#admin-users-table').DataTable().rows.remove() also what type does the add method take in as parameters for the values I need to render? Is this applicable to all versions of DataTable?